# iOS Locksmith cannot move stored data to from service "A" to service "B"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keychain, uickeychainstore

In one of my iOS apps I'm developing I'm storing some info in the Keychain. To interact with the keychain I am using Locksmith (https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith)

In version v1 of my app, I was writing some data in the keychain by using

```
Locksmith.saveData(data: data, forUserAccount:"A1", inService: "S1")
```

Now, in v2, I realized that I would like to migrate my data from "S1" to "S2", so I've set on to writing a small migration script to achieve this.

Essentially, what I am doing:

```
// read the old data
if let d = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount(userAccount: "A1", inService: "S1") {

   // write it in a new location
   Locksmith.saveData(data: d, forUserAccount: "A1", inService: "S2")
}
```

This is an oversimplification of my code.

The problem is that `d = nil` every time, although I know for sure it exists (when I am building the v1 of the app, I can see the data exists in that location).

Any ideas on this? Did somebody run into this problem before?

Some tech specs:

- Xcode 8.3
- Swift 3.1
- Locksmith 3.0 (via Carthage)
- iOS Simulator (iPhone 6s) running iOS 10.3

Didn't try on a real device.

Comment: Are you sure v2 has access to v1 keychain? Apps are sandboxed...

Comment: It's the same app, it has the same app identifier. v2 will be delivered as an update to v1.

Comment: Ok, figured it out! Somehow, in the process of developing v2, I changed the Target > Capabilities > Keychain Sharing > Keychain Group value. Therefore, I was trying to access a wrong keychain group. Everything working as expected now

Comment: I really thought that there was such a problem...

Comment: Yeah ... when you're wasting 4 hours trying to figure out what the problem might be ... this kind of stupid mistake evades your attention :) Nothing better than a 8 hour sleep to regain focus :))